# jQuery/javascript text selector similar to iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

im looking for a javascript/jquery plugin that will allow a user to select a word on a web page which once selected allows the user to drag a handle left/right if they want to expand the number of words they have selected. The iphone has exactly this when you double click on a word - does anyone know of such a tool?

Thanks in advance

Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible because you need HTML rendering engine to handle text/element flow. That's why there is (miserable) selection API in HTML specs. I suggest rethinking your problem in a way that doesn't  need such UI component.

Comment: Hi Skrat - you're absolutely right. The support in HTML is basically non-existent, I can only hope it improves in the future.